# Why cant I run 2 functions at one time?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyqt5

I'm trying to run several functions "stavka" at one time in btnClicked_2(). Getting errors:

```
    (<class 'TypeError'>, TypeError("cannot pickle 'mywindow' object"), <traceback object at 0x000000B2CF1C6240>)
    (<class 'EOFError'>, EOFError('Ran out of input'), <traceback object at 0x0000009EB6DDC9C0>)
```

I know that I cant use self as an argument but I need it in this function. Don't know what to do. Maybe I'm doing something wrong or it is not possible at all, please help.

```
    def stavka(self, AuctionID_raw, Price, data3, AuctionID, place):
       while True:
            .
            .
            .
    def btnClicked(self):
        .
        .
        .
    def btnCkicked_2(self):
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            proc = Process(target=self.stavka ,args=(AuctionID_raw, Price, data3, AuctionID, place,))
            procs[place] = proc
            proc.start()
```

With multithreading

```
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def run(self, AuctionID_raw, Price, data3, AuctionID, place):
        while True:
        login = self.lineEdit.text()
        .
        .
        .

class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
     def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.btnCkicked_2)
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.btnCkicked_3)

     def btnCkicked_2(self):
        .
        .
        .

        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run(AuctionID_raw, Price, data3, AuctionID, place))
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.thread.start()
```

Comment: GUI components (QWidgets) can only be used from the main application thread. Your `Worker` cannot have a GUI. You must pass to it all the data it needs to work with.

Comment: Pass data to Worker?

Comment: Yes. For example get data from GUI in main thread and then post data to Worker via signal/slot connection (these are thread safe). Or if you can init worker with all the data it needs in the first place.  BTW, I don't think you can `connect()` `thread.started` to the worker `run()` method like you do in 2nd example -- signal and slot parameters need to match, nor can you connect to a slot using actual data in the arguments. If your example runs at all, I suspect there is a Qt warning being printed to stderr.

Comment: @MaximPaperno , sorry for stupid questions but I can't understand what data should be passed to use GUI components and how should I pass it. If it is not hard for you can you edit my 2nd example. I'm a beginner, so hard for me to understand :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to call slots using multiprocessing, it's not possible since gui lives in one process, what multiprocessing module tries and fails to do: it tries to serialize your window using pickle (which doesn't make much sense - widgets are not copyable and not serializable), spawn another process and pass it to that process, which makes even less sense.

Just use multithreading, inherit `QThread`, put your function in `run()` method and `start()` it from main thread.

Comment: I tried multithreading and i still don't know how to edit QWidgets in my function.

Comment: As you can see in the code, in run() i need self from mywindow() to use lineedit.text() or do whatever with widgets

Comment: to pass data from gui thread to worker thread you can use signal-slot mechanism, create signal in you widget, connect this signal to worker's slot and emit signal with data, or create a singlal in worker thread that requests data, connect it to gui slot and pass data back using another signal, this is how we do it in gui realm